# How to pass a file (with path) as parameter of the method in Java

Tags: java, file, input, methods, path

I need to pass a file as parameter of the method in Java, in this way:

```
public void parse(String pathToExcelFile)
```

and so in Eclipse:

```
public void parse(String  "/Users/john/ExcelParses/test2.xls")
{... }
```

but I obtain this error:

> Syntax error on token ""/Users/john/ExcelParses/test2.xls"", invalid 
>    VariableDeclaratorId

Why? What is wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: File file=new File("your absolute path "); pass file as parameter

Comment: you are not passing a variable. `public void parse(String  "/Users/john/ExcelParses/test2.xls")` the string is not a variable. its an actual object. use `String path` and call the method with `parse("sdfasdf")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method declaration, you cannot use a String value. It needs to be a variable.

So, the method declaration stays the same:

```
public void parse(String pathToExcelFile)
```

and before calling the method, you can create the file, and pass the File object's path to the method:

```
File f = new File("filePath");
parse(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: The request that I did it was demad by teacher, but for me it feels strange.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing a method declaration and a method call.

This declares a method:

```
public void parse(String pathToExcelFile) { ... }
```

This calls the same method:

```
parse("/Users/john/ExcelParses/test2.xls");
```

Notice that we are passing a specific parameter value to the method in the call.

---

> The request that I did it was demad by teacher, but for me it feels strange.

In Java, you do not pass a specific parameter when you *declare* a method.  That simply doesn't make sense.  I suspect that you have misunderstood what your teacher was asking you to do.

Comment: I think you are right, thank you for your explanation.